# Restrict cash on delivery (cod) on opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I would like to know if there is a way to disable cod ( cash on delivery) when a product located in the cart.

I found this piece of code:

```
$weight = $this->getWeight();
if($weight>1)
{
$enabled=false;
}
```

and I am trying to put it in `cod.php`, but with no success.
thats what i am trying to do with this is: when a product has weight above 1 then disable cod.
could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution adding by #Johnathan

```
    IN:/catalog/model/payment/cod.php
    AFTER:
    public function getMethod($address, $total) {
    ADD:
    if ($this->cart->getWeight() > 1) return;
```

so now when i put in product details weight above 1, when this product is in cart it deactivate cod ( cash on delivery )